# find the largest substring that contains all of occurrence of a character

Tags: c#

I need to find out largest sub string that contains all of occurrence of a character in C#.

Example  - Input string : "my name is granar"
Nee to find out largest sub string that contains all of occurrence of a character "a", the result is "**ame is grana**"

Please help me in algorithm?

Comment: Substring(IndexOf('a'), LastIndexOf('a') - IndexOf('a'))

Comment: Where is your code! What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. > Algorithm: int begin = -1, end = -1
2. > In a for loop
   >       save first index of 'a' in begin and end
   >       keep updating end every time you encounter 'a'
3. > strinput.substring(begin,end)

   ```
    static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           int begin = -1, end = -1;

           string input = "my name is granar";

           bool isfirst = true;
           for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
           {
               if(input[i] == 'x')
               {
                   if (isfirst)
                   {
                       begin = i;
                       end = i;
                       isfirst = false;
                   }
                   else
                       end = i;
               }
           }

           if (begin != -1)
           {
               string substr = input.Substring(begin, end - begin + 1);

               Console.WriteLine(substr);
           }
           else Console.WriteLine("Not Found");
           Console.ReadKey();
       }
   ```

> This is a better algorithm for larger string, as we are iterating through the entire string only once.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
var text = "my name is granar";
var firstA = text.IndexOf("a");
var LastA = text.LastIndexOf("a");
int length = LastA - firstA + 1;
if (firstA != -1)
    var result = text.Substring(firstA, length);
```

Comment: One line is not always better than multiple. You are doing things more than once, it's also not safe if there is none `a` you'll get an exception. Use variables as in your first version ;)

Comment: calling two IndexOf functions increases complexity of your solution. Internally it will run O(n) twice.

Comment: Hmm I had the answer multi line but it is so simple that I think it should be a one line solution.

Comment: Your right @Renuka. Modified

Comment: @JamesDev: still the possible exception, +1 anyway